# How do I upload a file through Ajax and php without form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to upload a file to the same place in the server, The file is a html file the is created through javascript. I currently have it set up so I am able to create and download the file (Contents is equal to some text) This part works. I am trying to make it so that on button press instead of the page providing me a link to download the file, the file gets upload to a folder on the webserver.

The text file is made with the following code:

```
  makeTextFile = function (text) {
  var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
  if (textFile !== null) {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
  }

  textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

  return textFile;
};

link.href = makeTextFile(contents);
```

This is the Ajax code:

```
 var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("file", textFile);
    $.ajax({
    url:"upload.php",
    method:"POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend:function(){
    console.log("File Uploading");
    },   
  success:function(data)
    {
     console.log("File Uploaded: " + data);
    }
 });
```

upload.php

```
if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '')
{
 $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 $ext = end($test);
 $name = rand(100, 999) . '.' . $ext;
 $location = '/uploads/' . $name;  
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
 echo '<img src="'.$location.'" height="150" width="225" class="img-thumbnail" />';
}
?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the current problem? You already seem to have all the parts together so which part does not work?

Comment: @SaschaM78 The file is not uploading, the console logs "File Uploading" and then "File Uploaded: " But with no data, just that. It also doesnt come up with any php erros or anything.

Comment: add this line top of the php file `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and please check do you have permission in target folder